# Azure websites web.config not updating

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I see this in my web.config when I access via FTP (and this certainly seems to be the behavior of the server).

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="pythonpath" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="DjangoApplication.settings" />   
</appSettings>
```

However, my configuration in the Azure control panel is as follows

[image: Azure control panel settings]

Why don't they match? I have restarted the app many times, and had multiple deployments (via Github hook) that haven't seemed to help. There is also some random DjangoApplication folder present that is not part of my deployment.

Comment: Are you deploying to the same slot?  If not this would explain the differences. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/

Comment: Thanks Simon, good thought, but I'm still trying to get it to work on the trial membership so slots aren't even available to me: it says "You must be in Standard mode to enable staged publishing" when I try to create a slot as a test.

Comment: Are you uploading the new files to the right location on the target FTP server? (sorry if you are). I'd recommend tearing it all down and setup a new site to validate if you get this issue on another site.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not FTP uploading anything. The deployment to my site is done via the Azure-Github integration. I only accessed FTP to debug why it seemed to be using the wrong settings module. Repro: set up a new "Django application" site, and then change the config in the UI.

Comment: To be clear, I was easily able to fix this by just modifying the file via FTP, but it was a frustrating bug :)

Answer (score 2):

The Portal `App Settings` supersede the Web.config `appSettings`. These will not be in sync unless you manually or script to update the Portal settings based on your web.config settings.

Comment: OK - interesting, thanks. I would have presumed them to be the same. In that case, I guess my question is instead why the Portal App Settings didn't seem to be doing anything? (I had to update the web.config appSettings with the values I set in the portal originally for anything to happen).

Comment: How are you accessing these settings?  The values provided via the portal will overwrite the web.config at run time (the actual file won't be updated).  This is a pretty good run down: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/07/17/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/